# Algebraic subgroup of ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

A $1$-dimensional connected algebraic subgroup of ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^n$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^1$ if the ground field is perfect.

Are there any references concerning the structure of closed subgroups of ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^n$ ?

> Does a closed subgroup of ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^n$ of dimension $k$ embedd in ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^{k}$ (for $K$ algebraically closed say) ?

If $K$ has characteristic $0$, then a closed subgroup of ${\mathbf G}_{\mathbf a}^n$ is a $K$-vector space, so the above obviously holds.

Comment: By algebraic, do you mean a closed subgroup?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes I do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Namely, take something like

$$\alpha_p=V(x^p-x)\subseteq\mathbf{G}_a$$

which is a zero-dimensional subgroup of $\mathbf{G}_a$ which does not embed in $\mathbf{G}_a^0$. A less stupid example can be obtained by considering something like $\mathbf{G}_a\times\alpha_p\subseteq\mathbf{G}_a^2$ which can't be embedded in $\mathbf{G}_a$.

As you pointed out, in characteristic $0$ every unipotent group is a vector group (i.e. isomorphic to a direct sum of $\mathbf{G}_a$). For all concerns related to unipotent groups you can see [this](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0070517) book.